# Необходимо написать функцию которая создает квадратичную единичную матрицу, не применяя библиотеку NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, for

```
def build_array(n):
    m = [[for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
    m[i][i] = 1
    
    return m
```

Выдает ошибку по синтаксису. В чем ошибка, не могу понять?

Comment: Вы предлагаете нам сначала немножко поугадывать какая у вас ошибка, чтобы нам было не скучно?? :-D

Comment: invalid syntax.

Comment: Вы не задумывались зачем Python выдает такой большой и подробный `error traceback`? ;)

Comment: У вас цикл есть, а функции для элемента нету.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка заключается в том, что вы не указали функцию присвоения элемента для `[for i in range(n)]`, т.е. должна быть форма `[f(i) for i in range(n)]`, `f(i)` - функция присвоения зависящая от i.

Говоря другими словами, данный код:

```py
m = [f(i) for i in range(n)]
```

эквивалентен cледующему коду(ведет себя аналогично):

```py
m = []
for i in range(n):
    m.append(f(i))
```

Более подробно [читайте официальную документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions).

Можно инициализировать таблицу нулями, а затем установить единицы по диагонали(это если вам нужна единичная матрица, а не матрица заполненная единицами), но проще решить задачу следующим образом:

```py
def build_array(n):
    return [[int(i==j) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

Comment: Это не единичная матрица

Comment: @AlexAlex, а сейчас? )

Comment: Сейчас - да. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Вот самая настоящая единичная матрица, аналог np.eye() (не путать с матрицей состоящей из единиц np.ones()):

```
def build_array(n):
    return [[1 if i==j else 0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
def build_array(n):
    return [[1 for _ in range(n)] for __ in range(n)]
```

Если нужна единичная матрица:

```
def build_array(n):
    return [[int(i==j) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

Comment: Это не единичная матрица

Comment: @AlexAlex, я тоже был слегка озадачен несоответствием описания и кода и подумал, что автор вопроса имеет ввиду матрицу состоящую из всех единиц) Добавил вариант для единичной матрицы...

Comment: кстати т.к. тип bool наследуется от int, то можно писать просто `i == j`. матрица будет ввести точно также, отличаться будет только вывод

Comment: @Danis, спасибо, я в курсе, но вид будет совершенно другой. Мы же не знаем для чего автору вопроса нужна эта матрица)

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один вариант:

```
m = ((1,) * n,) * n
```

Comment: это хулиганский вариант) Попробуйте поменять значение одного элемента в m.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru исправил ;)

Comment: - Доктор, когда я вот вот так вот делаю у меня болит..((
- А вы вот вот так вот не делайте ))))

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension должен быть такого вида

```
[i for i in range(n)]
```

а у вас просто

```
[for i in range(n)]
```

поэтому и происходит ошибка

Чтобы единицы стояли под догнали место перед for допишите `1 if i == j else 0`

```
[[1 if i == j else 0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

Comment: @MaxU очепятка :D